# How to find where a Python class is defined

Tags: python

Let's say I have a number in Python project and I want to find out in what package/module a particular class is defined (I know the class name). Is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Are you asking programatically or just in general?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31166641/3001761

Comment: @stazima Any way would work for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) module to get the location where a module/package is defined.

```
inspect.getmodule(my_class)
```

Sample Output:

```
<module 'module_name' from '/path/to/my/module.py'>
```

As per the docs,

> inspect.getmodule(object)
>   Try to guess which module an object was defined in.

Comment: do you know what the guessing part means? when will it get it wrong?

Comment: Use `inspect.getmodule(my_class).__file__` to get the guessed file name.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain by example

```
import numpy
print numpy.__file__
```

gives

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc
```

on my machine.

If you only have a class, you can use that class with the python2-ic `imp` module:

```
#let unknownclass be looked for

import imp

modulename = unknownclass.__module__
tup = imp.find_module(modulename)
#(None, '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy', ('', '', 5))
print "path to module", modulename, ":", tup[1]
#path to module numpy : /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
```

As you can see, the `__module__` property is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: That gives the location of a module/package, not a class.

Comment: That's how python works; modules have files, which contain classes. Of course, there might be automatic class finding based on file names, but it's generally not like a class must come from a file, so this is not really something that you can expect of python -- finding the module where the class is from is in many cases the closest you get.

Comment: That is true, but that makes it the answer to a different question :) Not downvoting, just pointing it out.

Comment: Much better, great change :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the location of a class is using a combination of the `__module__` attribute of a class and the `sys.modules` dictionary.

Example:

```
import sys
from stl import stl

module = sys.modules[stl.BaseStl.__module__]
print module.__file__
```

I should note that this doesn't always give the correct module, it just gives the module where you got it from. A more thorough (but slower) method is using the `inspect` module:

```
from stl import stl
import inspect

print inspect.getmodule(stl.BaseStl).__file__
```