# How can an imported class know it's originating import path

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following: -

```
from x.y.z import Foo
```

How can `Foo` know the originating `x.y.z` without explicitly telling it.

Comment: print(Foo.__file__) will print the file location

Comment: @mamun I think `Foo.__name__` is more appropriate to the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom You mean `Foo.__qualname__`? Or better yet, `Foo.__module__`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346452/how-to-find-where-a-python-class-is-defined) is a suitable duplicate I think?

Comment: @Aran-Fey It is. The `__module__` attribute of a class object will do.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I just did a `dir(module)` on a module I had already imported that was sitting around; `__file__` and `__name__` were in the list, but `__qualname__` and `__module__` were not. That's with Python 3.6.

Comment: @MarkRansom Modules don't have those attributes, classes do.

Comment: @Aran-Fey the example I used was `from PIL import Image`, which fits the pattern given in the question. How is one to know the difference between a class and a module when importing?

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, generally speaking class names are capitalized and module names aren't. PIL doesn't care much about good practices though...

Comment: @Aran-Fey and `datetime` is both a module and a class, so bad practices aren't restricted to badly written packages.