# Getting Module from Type

Tags: python, python-2.6

Is there a way in Python to get the module from a type ? I have an object which I can get the type but I am unable to see where the type is defined.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31166088/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.getmodule`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) to retrieve the module object the specified object was defined in.

For example:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> inspect.getmodule(c)
<module 'collections' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python34\\lib\\collections\\__init__.py'>
>>> inspect.getmodule(Counter)
<module 'collections' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python34\\lib\\collections\\__init__.py'>
```

Comment: On this particular example, I am getting <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>

Comment: Then it’s part of the *builtin* module which is built into the interpreter.